# With a Mongoose schema, Is it possible to define the type of an objects property/keys that are unknown?

Tags: mongoose

For example I have an object as follows:

```
{
    foo: "string",
    bar: "another string",
    baz: 4                  // Incorrect type
}
```

I do not know the names of the objects properties (foo, bar, baz) but I want each property to only be of the type String and so therefor "baz" would be rejected/throw error.

What would the Model Schema look like for this data? The only way I could possibly see of doing this would be with using a Custom Type similar to the Mixed Type for the whole Object/Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option for "wild card" schema path validation as far as I know.
What you can do is define a `strict: false` schema and define a `pre save and update` functions.

The schema would look like this:

```
var TestSchema  = new mongoose.Schema(
    {

    },
    {
        strict: false
    }
);
```

it means that there are no defined fields and you can enter any field you want. Now you want to validate the document before saving with a `pre save` function:

```
TestSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var doc = this.toObject();
    for (var prop in doc) {
        if ('string' !== typeof doc[prop]) {
            next(new Error('validation error'));
        }
    }

    next();
});
```

You would want to do same on `pre update` function. you can read more about `mongoose` `Middleware` here:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html